# How to mock geolocation in ARCore

Tags: kotlin, geospatial, arcore

I'm building a app that is using the geospatial API from ARCore. The indoor localization is obviously not very accurate, but to make the development process easier im trying to mock my device location.

Im able to create a mocked location with the system location manager.

```
fun setMockLocation(lat: Double, lng: Double, alt: Double) {
    val provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
    val locationManager: LocationManager =
        this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    locationManager.removeTestProvider(provider)

    locationManager.addTestProvider(
        provider,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        ProviderProperties.POWER_USAGE_LOW,
        ProviderProperties.ACCURACY_FINE
    )

    val mockLocation = android.location.Location(provider)
    mockLocation.latitude = lat
    mockLocation.longitude = lng
    mockLocation.altitude = alt
    mockLocation.time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    mockLocation.accuracy = 5.0f
    mockLocation.elapsedRealtimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()

    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true)
    locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, mockLocation)
}
```

But it seems that the ARCore Earth is not using this location, because the obtained GeospatialPose is always different from the mocked location.

Any idea how I can mock the GeospatialPose obtained from ARCore? Or how to force ARCore to use the mocked location.

Comment: Then, instead of using the location from the GeospatialPose class, use your mocked location when creating your anchor ```val earthAnchor =
  earth.createAnchor(mockLocation.latitude, mockLocation.longitude, altitude, qx, qy, qz, qw)```
However, since the Geospatial API uses StreetView images to improve the location and compass, I don't think using it indoors would produce good results. Instead, you can use local anchors.